# Mongoose method function undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and adding method functions, when i use model.find()
and run model.fnname(), it's undefined

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var timestamps = require('goodeggs-mongoose-timestamps');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var OrderSchema=new Schema({

    code:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    percentage:{
        type: String,
        required:false,
    },


});
OrderSchema.methods.updateProductionStatus = function updateProductionStatus() {
    this.percentage="88%";
    return;
}
OrderSchema.plugin(timestamps);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);
```

Controller Code

```
let order=await Order.findOne();
console.log(order) //this is working
order.updateProductionStatus(); ///this is undefined
```

any ideas?

Edit

Found out that the above example is working, but

```
let orders=await Order.aggregate(........);
console.log(orders[0]) ///works
orders[0].updateProductionStatus() //isn't working
```

Comment: Is the code `const order1 = new Order({ code : 'abcd', percentage : '28%' }); order1.updateProductionStatus();` working ?

Comment: yess and findOne,find is working too, but aggregate no, is that normal ? @Martial

Comment: Does it work with callback instead of  `await` syntax ? `Order.aggregate(........, function(err, orders){ orders[0].updateProductionStatus(); });`

Comment: @Martial No, same as await